# Insert into db table (query 2) from another table (query 1) in php

Tags: php, html, mysql, dropdown

Hi I have a drop down list that has values from one db table 
and I want on button click to save the row of the specific id in another table
I have this form

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-responsive">
    <tr>
    <td><label class="control-label">Drop down list</label></td>
    <td class="col-xs-4">
        <?php
            $stmt01 = $DB_con->prepare('SELECT * FROM dbtable WHERE chart in (458,459,461) ORDER BY id ASC');
            $stmt01->execute();
            if($stmt01->rowCount() > 0)
            {
            ?>
                <select class="form-control" name="value01">
                    <?php
                        while($row=$stmt01->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
                        {
                            extract($row);
                            echo '<option value="'.$row['id'].'">'.$row['id'].' '.$row['lastName'].' '.$row['firstName'].'</option>';
                        }
                    ?>
                </select>
            <?php
            }
            ?>
        </td>
        <td colspan="2" align="right" class="col-md-2"><button type="submit" name="btnsave01" class="btn btn-default">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-save"></span> &nbsp; Insert
            </button>
        </td>
    </tr>
```

And my php is

```
require_once 'dbconfig.php';
if (isset($_POST['btnsave01']))
{
    if (isset($_POST['value01']))
    {
        $chart = $_GET['chart'];
        $chartDescription = $_GET['chartDescription'];
        $lastName = $_GET['lastName'];
        $firstName = $_GET['firstName'];
        $location = $_GET['location'];
        $empPic = $_GET['empPic'];

        $q01 = $DB_con->prepare('INSERT INTO results01(chart,chartDescription,regNo,lastName,firstName,location,empPic) VALUES(:uchart, :uchartDescription, :uregNo, :ulastName, :ufirstName, :ulocation, uempPic)');
        $q01->bindParam(':uchart',$chart);
        $q01->bindParam(':uchartDescription',$chartDescription);
        $q01->bindParam(':uregNo',$regNo);
        $q01->bindParam(':ulastName',$lastName);
        $q01->bindParam(':ufirstName',$firstName);
        $q01->bindParam(':ulocation',$location);
        $q01->bindParam(':uempPic',$empPic);
    }
}
```

Can you help me fix this?
The button is working fine but the value is not stored inside db table

Thank you

Comment: @ManojSharma 
All edited and fixed by your answers but I am getting this error
`Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'chart' cannot be null'
( ! ) PDOException: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'chart' cannot be null`

Comment: Thank you all for helping
I fixed it by another thought I came up
Thanks again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2 corrections in your `PHP`

1. Missing `:` in `VALUES` of `INSERT` query. Replace `uempPic` with `:uempPic`.
2. `INSERT` query is not executed. Add below line after last `bindParam` statement.

   ```
   $q01->execute();
   ```

Comment: I printed all php variable $chart etc
and all of them are null 
SQLSTATE[23000] 
Why my code doesn't get the selected id from dropdown columns?

Comment: Can you help why I am getting null values ?

Comment: That's because, you have submitted values using `POST` and are fetched with `$_GET`. Use `$_POST` instead to retrieve values submitted.

Comment: I changed that and now I am using `$_POST` but have null values from the dropdown to insert to the other table on submit

Answer (score 0):

Error at this line please check it...

```
 $q01 = $DB_con->prepare('INSERT INTO results01(chart,chartDescription,regNo,lastName,firstName,location,empPic) VALUES(:uchart, :uchartDescription, :uregNo, :ulastName, :ufirstName, :ulocation, :uempPic)');
```

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look on your prepare statement:

> $q01 = $DB_con->prepare('INSERT INTO results01(chart,chartDescription,regNo,lastName,firstName,location,empPic) VALUES(:uchart, :uchartDescription, :uregNo, :ulastName, :ufirstName, :ulocation, uempPic)');

You have forgot to add ":" with "uempPic", Please use below statement.

> $q01 = $DB_con->prepare('INSERT INTO results01(chart,chartDescription,regNo,lastName,firstName,location,empPic) VALUES(:uchart, :uchartDescription, :uregNo, :ulastName, :ufirstName, :ulocation, :uempPic)');

You have not included execute statement. Add below statement after bindParam.

> $q01->execute();

I think your insert issue will get resolved.

Comment: It means , you should check the value of field 'chart', It should have some value. Please try to print your query and check the value of $chart variable. when $chart will fix then it will work.

Comment: The 1st db table is full of values and represented correctly in other page views
The thing is that I cannot copy these from the dropdown to the other empty db table with the same columns
The $chart variable should contain the chart row column value 
Something I am not doint correct in my code

Comment: All of the fields values are null 
I var dumped them and they did not get value from dropdown

Comment: Actually you have not posted whole Form code at here, But I will ask you to verify this points. 1. Please let me know form method. If you are not able to do please change $_GET to $_REQUEST. 1 more thing to remember I am not able to see name of this drop-down, Please set the name of this drop-down then definitely you will get the value of $chart.

Comment: 1. form method = post
2. name of the dropdown <select class="form-control" name="value01">

I've change the GET to REQUEST and getting null values same SQL error

I want to take all data from dbtable (as I picked the id from the dropdown) to resultsdbtable with same columns (empty at first and as I press button insert will copy the row to the result table)

Comment: 1. Change dorop-down name to "chart";
2. where you are assigning the value to variable like $chart, need to change $_GET to $_POST OR $_REQUEST then your problem get resolved.

Comment: :string '1558' (length=4)

:null

:null

:null

:null

:null

:null

The only change made by this change of drop-down name and POST or REQUEST and the chart is representing false value

Comment: Please change with other variables as well and also Please cross verify the name of all fields what you have defined in form and what you are using at the time of assigning values to variable like $chart = $_GET['chart'];

Comment: This is not working at all
Checked it several times
everytime is passing null as value of variables from the drop-down